# Add column skipping nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Series with NaNs and an array with the same length excluding NaNs values:

```
s = pd.Series([8, np.NaN, 5, 6, np.NaN, 3])
a = np.ndarray([2, 1, 0, 4])
```

I want to obtain a Dataframe adding to the Series a column with the array values skipping the NaNs present on the series:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'s': [8, np.NaN, 5, 6, np.NaN, 3],
                   'a': [2, np.NaN, 1, 0, np.NaN, 4]})
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Do you wish to add a NaN at every index where `Series s` has a Nan? Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These straightforward solutions achieves that:

Option 1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([8, np.NaN, 5, 6, np.NaN, 3])
a = np.array([2, 1, 0, 4])

values = a.tolist()

res = pd.DataFrame({'s': s})

res["a"] = [np.NaN if np.isnan(x) else values.pop(0) for i, x in s.iteritems()]

print(res)
```

Option 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([8, np.NaN, 5, 6, np.NaN, 3])
a = np.array([2, 1, 0, 4])

# Convert values to list
values = a.tolist()

# Add nan where needed
for nans_index in [i for i, x in s.iteritems() if np.isnan(x)]:
    values.insert(nans_index, np.nan)

# Set as new dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame({'s': s, 'a' : values})

print(res)
```

Output:

```
     s    a
0  8.0  2.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  5.0  1.0
3  6.0  0.0
4  NaN  NaN
5  3.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove nan from dataframes,

```
res = res.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

for column you can use ton of things,I personally use one liners to edit my columns.

```
res["a"] = [i if isinstance(i , int) for i in res["a"]]
```